# Clang compiler couldn't find C/C++ standard libraries when I gave a specific target although it works without giving target

Tags: c++, c, ubuntu, clang, riscv

I am currently using clang11 on ubuntu to compile any c/c++ code and it works fine but when I tried to compile any code (including [any standard library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header)) to assembly code for any specific target like `x86_64` (even I have x86_64)  `riscv` with giving a flag that `--target=x86_64` or `--target=riscv32` I got errors for any standard library that I included in my code. A simple example:

```
// ex.cpp
#include<iostream>
int main(){
    int a = 5;
    int b = 3;
    std::cout << a - b;
}
```

Without giving flag for a spesific target works fine:

`clang++-11 -S ex.cpp -o ex.s`

With `--target=riscv32` flag:

`clang++-11 --target=riscv32 -S ex.cpp -o ex.s`

gives this error:
`ex.cpp:1:9: fatal error: 'iostream' file not found`

also without standard libraries gives no error even I give a spesific target.

I am searching for a solution for days but I couldn't find any proper solution for this problem, most of them says try to include gnu libraries and subfolders like `-I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/` but it doesn't work for me.

Please don't say use g++ compiler, for adding an optimization I need clang.

Actually I am trying to compile my codes for riscv target, linking with g++ and running with spike (doesn't differ `--target=...` or `-target ...`):

```
clang++-11 -target riscv32-unknown-elf -march=rv32gc -fno-addrsig -S ex.cpp -o ex.s
~/riscv/bin/riscv32-unknown-elf-g++ ex.s -o ex
~/riscv/riscv-isa-sim/build/spike --isa=RV32GC ~/riscv/riscv-pk/build/pk ex
```

And it works fine without include a standard library.
Now, I want to ask that

Can I solve this problem simply?

or

Can I use clang directly from riscv bin utils like `~/riscv/bin/riscv32-unknown-elf-clang++` (I saw something like this on the net but couldn't find) adding and building a submodule to my riscv directory?

Edit: As @NateEldredge said, for x86_64 target triple should `--target=x86_64-linux-gnu` but for riscv as a target triple `riscv32-unknown-elf` I still have the same errors. Is there a proper target flag for riscv any other than `--target=riscv32-unknown-elf`? Maybe I am missing that point.

Comment: Are you compiling as C or C++?  Is your code C or C++?  They are distinct languages.  For example, C++ has `std::string` and `std::vector`, which would be different libraries than C.  Please update your tags and question about which language you are using.

Comment: You probably need to install heaers and libraries for the other targets

Comment: @M.M How can I install, especially for riscv? Also, as I said even I give x86_64 for target I get same error although I am working on x86_64 and also I can compile without no error without no target flag.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Sorry but as you can see, I just gave an example for C++, this is a general problem for me even if compiler is clang (for C) or clang++ (for C++) because of that I am asking general. For example, if I try to compile a C code with stdio.h library I get same error like `fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found` and so forth for any other library.

Comment: Shouldn't the argument to `--target` be a [target triplet](https://wiki.osdev.org/Target_Triplet), not just an architecture?  So `--target=x86_64-linux-gnu` instead of just `x86_64`.  Running `clang -v` should show you what the default target triplet is.

Comment: More generally, you can use the verbosity flag (`-v`), to see what libraries and include paths are implicitly used.

Comment: @NateEldredge Right, I will edit my post, missed that thing target triple should `--target=x86_64-linux-gnu` and it works but it is weird that without including a library, codes are compiling with just like `--target=x86_64` but this is not the case :) Actually I need specify a target because I don't use on my x86, I need for riscv and I tried for riscv as a target triple `riscv32-unknown-elf` or `riscv32-none-elf` and also tried for arm like `arm-none-eabi` but noone works. Probably a proper target triple will work but couldn't find for riscv just find  `riscv32-unknown-elf` that doesnt work.

Comment: How did you build and install your riscv32 cross compiler?  Using `--target` with the installed clang binary will search for its files in a specific place, which maybe is not where you have them installed.

Comment: OT but quite irritating: a **_header file_** is not a **_library_**. It may define parts or all of the public API of one or more libraries, but not necessarily. It can even be empty. -- A library might be needed later when linking, but you are just compiling. Please get used to the proper terms.

Comment: @NateEldredge Actually I didn't build a cross compiler firstly, just built [llvm-project](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project) with `-DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD=all` option and used clang compiler from this built, because after llvm 9 i know llvm support came for riscv target. (All supported targets can be seen [here](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/2c4ca6832fa6b306ee6a7010bfb80a3f2596f824/include/llvm/ADT/Triple.h#L43).) I mean as llvm promised I should have been able to used clang for all targets with llvm in built but didn't work for me.

Comment: I just solved my problem cross compilation with [riscv-llvm repo](https://github.com/sifive/riscv-llvm) which has not updated for a long time and is not official for now. I didn't understand that why llvm has a support for riscv but I couldn't use its clang compiler for this spesific target, why I need a cross compilation or if I need that how I can cross compile riscv gnu toolchain with official llvm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved my problem by linking compilations with [riscv-gnu-toolchain](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-gnu-toolchain) built and also answered a similar question here in detailed: [Using Clang to compile for RISC-V](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68580399/using-clang-to-compile-for-risc-v)

Simply we need `cross-compilation`.
Further information you can also look here: https://github.com/lowRISC/riscv-llvm#how-can-i-build-upstream-llvmclang-and-use-it-to-cross-compile-for-a-riscv32-target